# Reputation grovelling comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Should "reputation grovelling" comments posted by the answerer, eg

> Please upvote this answer. It's the best one!

be deleted? (Not sure what mechanism would be best)

Also, is there a term used to describe users who post such comments?

Comment: Just flag them as "not constructive".

Comment: OK. What about a term? Is there a nickname used?

Comment: Okay, if someone posts that comment on somebody else's answer, fine, it's just superfluous. But posting that on one's own? Blerk.

Comment: Pff, don't know about a semi-official nickname, no. I can come up with a few, but I'd like to keep my account.

Comment: One adjective that comes to mind is "lame."

Comment: ^----- please upvote my witty comment!

Comment: Oh, go on then, for you, @Pekka웃.